# Where do I obtain the values of client_id and client_secret for use with POST /4.0/oauth/token

Tags: social-tables

I’m currently storing the Token in order to access the social tables web service but now realise tokens expire after just 2 weeks. I presume I need to use the POST token function to get a new one? If so, where do I find the values for client_id and client_secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a Social Tables App in order to use our oauth routes. Here are some nice instructions from our docs:

https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/docs/apps/

Once you have your client_id and client_secret, you will be able to use the oauth authorization flow to allow user to grant your app access to their data.

https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/docs/authentication

Please feel free to post a follow up if this process gives you any trouble.